# Group Book Orders by Author

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting, group-by, nested-loops

I have created a functioning e-commerce platform where Members can buy books. Everything works fine, But I would like to group all of my Orders in my Index Page by Author.

Currently I am able to group each Author, but then every existing Book Order gets listed under each Author. As oppose to only listing the Book Orders corresponding to that Author.

```
EX. of what I'd like in my Orders Page

###Orders grouped by Authors
Author1
  Book1 belongs_to Author1   ###BookOrders grouped by Author
  Book2 belongs_to Author1  
  Book3 belongs_to Author1

Author2
  Book1 belongs_to Author2
  Book2 belongs_to Author2

Author3
  Book1 belongs_to Author3
```

**MODELS**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :author_id, :book_id, :user_id, :order_date

  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user

end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible : author_id, :title, :price

  belongs_to : author
  has_many :orders
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :books
end
```

CONTROLLER

```
def index  

  ###How Can I combine this so it Groups Book Orders By Author  

  ###Groups Orders by Author
  @orders = Order.find(:all, :order => 'author_id, id', :limit => 50)
  @author_orders = @orders.group_by { |order| order.book.author.name }

  ###Groups Orders by Book
  @orders = Order.find(:all, :order => 'author_id, id', :limit => 50)
  @book_orders = @orders.group_by { |order| order.book.title }

end
```

VIEWS

```
<% @author_orders.each do |author, orders| %>
  <h2><%= author %> </h2>

  <% @book_orders.each do |book, orders| %>
     <h4><%= book %> </h4>

  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not instead:

Model:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :books
  has_many :orders, through: :books
end
```

Controller:

```
def index  
  @authors = Author.includes(:orders)
end
```

View

```
<% @authors.each do |author| %>
  <h2><%= author.name %> </h2>

  <% author.orders.each do |order| %>
     <h4><%= order.book.title %> </h4>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

### Update:

To display only those authors who have an order you need unfortunately to do some gymnastics. Also previous `includes` will not save you completely from N+1 and needs to be improved.

```
  @authors = Author.includes(orders: :books).where('orders.id IS NOT NULL')
```

Comment: How does `@authors = Author.includes(:orders)` help?

Comment: @JohnC - Thanks, typo. `includes` is only there to avoid N+1 problem.

Comment: @BroiSatse This works pretty well, but it also lists all the current authors vs authors with actual orders.

Answer (score 1):

You are really close I think.

You just need to get your books from the order that belongs to the author.

Like this...

```
<% @author_orders.each do |author, orders| %>
  <h2><%= author %> </h2>

  <% orders.each do |order| %>
     <h4><%= order.book %> </h4>

  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

Comment: this solution is giving me all of the ordered books under every author. so some authors even contain books that don't belong to them.

Comment: Make sure you have `orders.each` not `@orders.each`